# Conditionally run a mvn plugin if a specific directory doesn't exist

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is it possible to conditionally run a maven plugin only if a specific directory doesn't exist?

I'm essentially trying to prevent `npm ci` from running unnecessarily as package.json rarely changes. So ideally it would only run when `node_modules` doesn't exists.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>npm-install</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>npm</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>ci</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For npm I would suggest to take a look at: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it into a profile and activate that profile only if a given file does not exist.